# C++ indexing beyond an array's size

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

My code takes an int input and sets that as the array's size, and I have some test prints that print out the index of the array starting from 0 to 4..

```
std::cout<<array[0]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<array[1]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<array[2]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<array[3]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<array[4]<<std::endl;
```

However, I noticed that if the `input` is smaller than 5, say `2` for instance, then the first two `cout` print out correctly, but then the rest print out `0` or random numbers like `17` and `135137`. Is this an out of bounds thing that happens when you index beyond the array size or is this a problem in my code? (I know I have to change the print statements)

The arrays are dynamically allocated by the way, which I think shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could you please display the code that allocates and initializes `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an out of bounds thing that happens when you index beyond the array size or is this a problem in my code?

Both.

Assuming `array` itself has a size of at least 5 elements, the initial contents of it before you set the values to anything are undefined; essentially random (they're just whatever happened to be hanging out in that particular block of memory that your array now occupies). If `array` itself has a size of less than 5, the values are still undefined but accessing them also runs the risk of crashing the program. In either case, the fact that you are printing values beyond the end of the initialized, valid data in your array is a problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate an array of `n` elements, accessing the `(n+1)`th element is undefined behaviour (UB). (Note after comments: The `(n+1)`th element is the element with index `n`. So if `array` has only size 3, accessing `array[3]` already causes UB).

So, yes it is an "out of bounds thing" and it is a problem of your code (because it's you who accesses the array beyond its size.

Why not loop to print out simply the existing element instead of hardcoding the indices?

Comment: Since an array index is 0 based, accessing the nth element is undefined behavior.

Comment: His answer says it´s the (n+1)th element. It does not say it has index (n+1). I too would add the index aspect to the question, though.

Comment: @BenKey Incorrect. The 5th element in an array of size 5 the is element with *index* 4 which is of course valid. The element with *index* 5 is the **6th** element of the array and accessing it causes UB.